# Python: Dict reading did not always succeed

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm making a python script that must read a dictionary of this type

```
{'error': [],
 'result': {'XXBTZEUR': [[1507633993, '4074.00000', '4074.90000'],
                         [1507633994, '4074.00000', '4075.00000'],
                         [1507634006, '4074.50000', '4075.00000'],
                         [1507634043, '4074.50000', '4074.90000'],
                         [1507634046, '4074.50000', '4075.00000'],
                         [1507634046, '4074.50000', '4075.50000'],
                         [1507634056, '4075.00000', '4075.50000'],
                         [1507634064, '4075.00000', '4075.60000'],
                         [1507634064, '4074.50000', '4075.60000'],
                         [1507634119, '4075.00000', '4075.50000'],
                         [1507634122, '4075.50000', '4075.50000'],
                         [1507635113, '4075.50000', '4075.60000']],
                         'last': 1507635113}}
```

But in some executions reading through instruction

```
result = result['result'][pair]
```

where pair is in the example 'XXBTZEUR', it is not carried out correctly, and it will read the "last" field in the command does not appear.

Why?

I thank all those who will give me a hand and if the English is not written well.

Comment: Why is your variable named result and also the dictionary you're reading from? Shouldnt one be named differently

Comment: what is your problem in real, what are you trying to do it

Comment: I tried to change the name to the variable, but the result did not change. I used that instruction because the old content does not interest me

Comment: The problem is what I described, I also tested on a second machine and the problem itself

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. I created a `dict`, a variable `pair = 'XXBTZEUR'`, and when called `print(mydict['result'][pair])` the list of lists prints as expected. I suspect there is more code causing a problem that you are not showing here.

Comment: I found the problem, pulling the "pair = next(iter(result['result']))" instruction fetch the key name that contains the second large array in the dictionary but I checked and sometimes I get "last" instead of "XXBTZEUR". This is because I do not know the name of the key that contains the second big array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'last' entry is not stored in the array in the 'XXBTZEUR' entry, it's it's own entry in the dictionary stored in 'result'.

```
result['result']['XXBTZEUR']
```

gives the array as expected,
to get the 'last' entry you'd have to do

```
result['result']['last']
```

To make it easier to see:

```
{'error': 
    [],
    'result': {
          'XXBTZEUR': [[1507633993, '4074.00000', '4074.90000'],
                       [1507633994, '4074.00000', '4075.00000'],
                       [1507634006, '4074.50000', '4075.00000'],
                       [1507634043, '4074.50000', '4074.90000'],
                       [1507634046, '4074.50000', '4075.00000'],
                       [1507634046, '4074.50000', '4075.50000'],
                       [1507634056, '4075.00000', '4075.50000'],
                       [1507634064, '4075.00000', '4075.60000'],
                       [1507634064, '4074.50000', '4075.60000'],
                       [1507634119, '4075.00000', '4075.50000'],
                       [1507634122, '4075.50000', '4075.50000'],
                       [1507635113, '4075.50000', '4075.60000']],
          'last': 1507635113}}
```

Comment: this will help you

Comment: The problem is not to read the field "last," is that sometimes instead of reading the "XXBTZEUR" field (the "XXBTZEUR" value is stored in the variable "pair") read "last" field

Comment: so you want the big 2d array, but get the number (1507635113)?

Comment: Yes, I found the problem and wrote it in the comment above

Comment: @MicheleGiorgio then the problem is probably that the pair variable contains 'last' nad not 'XXBTZEUR' and the problem is elsewhere in your code.